# Not recognized variable inside a loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to run loop in Python while specifying the variable `x` and `y` inside the loop. When I run the following loop:

```
   my_funcs = {}
    for i in range(len(data) - 1):
        def foo(x, y):
            x = data[i]['body']
            y = data[i+1]['body']
            tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([x, y])
            return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]


        foo.func_name = "cosine_sim%d" % i
        my_funcs["cosine_sim%d" % i] = foo
        print(foo(x,y))
```

I get the strange error: `x is not defined` in the line `print(foo(x,y))` Any idea why on earth this might be happening since I have stated that `x = data[i]['body']` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you defining a function inside a loop? `x` is only defined within that function, so `foo(x, y)` doesn't know what `x` is

Comment: You don't mention which line generates the error, but I think it will be `print(foo(x,y))`, as you're trying to refer to `x` without ever assigning a value to it - you have stated that `x = data[i]['body']` but that's inside your function, and the print statement is outside the function

Comment: @ Simon Fraser you are absolutely right, so you suggest placing the print function right after return?

Comment: If it's in the function but after the return, it will never be reached, as the function will return. How you call the function will depend where you're getting x and y from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything else is correct, I think you should move that method outside of the loop.

You only defined `x` within `foo`, so the `print` line doesn't know about it. Plus, you were overwriting the `x` parameter of `foo` anyways

```
def foo(x, y):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([x, y])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]

my_funcs = {}
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    x = data[i]['body']
    y = data[i+1]['body']
    foo.func_name = "cosine_sim%d" % i
    my_funcs["cosine_sim%d" % i] = foo
    print(foo(x,y))
```